# How to update different cells with different identifiers in swift 5

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and I have this app in mind that basically needs to update all the cells based on the data received from one of the cells.

I am using dynamic cells and each one has a textfield inside.

**TableViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class MyCells: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var value_textfield: UITextField!

}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var units_length: [String] = ["Centimeter", "Meter", "Foot"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    units_length = units_length.sorted()
    self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return units_length.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = units_length[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"DINAlternate-Bold", size:30)

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    tableView.rowHeight = 100
}

}
```

Which function should I use to access all the cells with different identifiers and  simultaneously update all the textfield inside each cell?

I do have access to the textfield by having another class called MyCells, how should I implement it?
(I will not include the base ViewController class here as there's nothing inside)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use the function you already showed: `cellForRowAt`. You update your model data, tell the table to `reloadData`, `cellForRowAt` is called for all visible cells, and their values become the new values.

However if you are updating after every character, I would set up a notification broadcast situation and update all visible text fields and the model together without a reload. Just make sure the model and the table stay in sync in case the user scrolls and `cellForRow` is called.

Comment: Would it be possible for each textfield to update with each character typed in instead of waiting the entire Textfield to finish editing? It is a dynamic textfield with users' input so is it ok to reload the data constantly?

Comment: Ok in that case I would set up a notification broadcast situation and update all visible text fields and the model together without a reload. Just make sure the model and the table stay in sync in case the user scrolls and cellForRow is called.